# Camera Movement in a World Map

Tags: c#, xna

using XNA and C# I built a game as a tutorial, but I have since added functionality to allow the player to move around on a world map which requires the camera to "move"  but I no longer like the look of the if statements.

is there some way that I can clean this up?

```
private static Rectangle scrollArea = new Rectangle(150, 150, 500, 300);
```

---

```
private void repositionCamera(GameTime gameTime, Vector2 moveAngle)
{
    float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    float moveScale = playerSpeed * elapsed;

    if ((playerSprite.ScreenRectangle.X < scrollArea.X) && (moveAngle.X < 0))
    {
        Camera.Move(new Vector2(moveAngle.X, 0) * moveScale);
    }

    if ((playerSprite.ScreenRectangle.Right > scrollArea.Right) && (moveAngle.X > 0))
    {
        Camera.Move(new Vector2(moveAngle.X, 0) * moveScale);
    }

    if ((playerSprite.ScreenRectangle.Y < scrollArea.Y) && (moveAngle.Y < 0))
    {
        Camera.Move(new Vector2(0, moveAngle.Y) * moveScale);
    }

    if ((playerSprite.ScreenRectangle.Bottom > scrollArea.Bottom) && (moveAngle.Y > 0))
    {
        Camera.Move(new Vector2(0, moveAngle.Y) * moveScale);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generalize bodies of `if`s:

```
private static void MoveCamera(float x, float y, float moveScale)
{
    Camera.Move(new Vector2(x, y) * moveScale);
}

private void repositionCamera(GameTime gameTime, Vector2 moveAngle)
{
    float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    float moveScale = playerSpeed * elapsed;

    if ((playerSprite.ScreenRectangle.X < scrollArea.X) && (moveAngle.X < 0))
    {
        MoveCamera(moveAngle.X, 0, moveScale);
    }

    if ((playerSprite.ScreenRectangle.Right > scrollArea.Right) && (moveAngle.X > 0))
    {
        MoveCamera(moveAngle.X, 0, moveScale);
    }

    if ((playerSprite.ScreenRectangle.Y < scrollArea.Y) && (moveAngle.Y < 0))
    {
        MoveCamera(0, moveAngle.Y, moveScale);
    }

    if ((playerSprite.ScreenRectangle.Bottom > scrollArea.Bottom) && (moveAngle.Y > 0))
    {
        MoveCamera(0, moveAngle.Y, moveScale);
    }
}
```

Also I suggest to extract all those conditions to properties with clear names like:

```
private static bool IsCameraOutOfLeft =>
    playerSprite.ScreenRectangle.X < scrollArea.X && moveAngle.X < 0;

private static bool IsCameraOutOfRight =>
    playerSprite.ScreenRectangle.Right > scrollArea.Right && moveAngle.X > 0;

...
```

Then finally the `repositionCamera` method will be

```
private void repositionCamera(GameTime gameTime, Vector2 moveAngle)
{
    float elapsed = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
    float moveScale = playerSpeed * elapsed;

    if (IsCameraOutOfLeft || IsCameraOutOfRight)
    {
        MoveCamera(moveAngle.X, 0, moveScale);
    }

    if (IsCameraOutOfTop || IsCameraOutOfBottom)
    {
        MoveCamera(0, moveAngle.Y, moveScale);
    }
}
```

Also a method's name should be *PascalCased* – `RepositionCamera`.

Comment: ah, yes, back before I knew the good naming standards...lol

Comment: @Malachi if you don't know them anymore then you shoud return some of your rep :-P

Comment: I know them now, but when I first wrote this code I didn't know them well

Comment: lol, Visual Studio 2017 actually fixed the naming violation for me with a click of the mouse.

Comment: I am still working on this method, you have given me a good starting point to cleaning it up though, thank you